# Report duplicates in a list?

Tags: list

**Q:** how do I get only the duplicate elements in a list?

`delete-dups` (and `cl-delete-duplicates`) *deletes* all duplicate
elements from a list:

```
(delete-dups '(a b c c d d))            ; => '(a b c d)
```

I want the reverse: is there a function that returns *only* the
duplicates in a list?

```
(mystery-function '(a b c c d d))       ; => '(c d)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use [hash tables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hash-Tables.html):

```
(defun get-duplicates (list &optional test)
  (let ((ht (make-hash-table :test (or test #'equal))) 
        ret)
    (dolist (x list)
      (incf (gethash x ht 0)))
    (maphash (lambda (key value)
               (when (> value 1)
                 (push key ret)))
             ht)
    ret))
(get-duplicates '(a 2 a b 3 2))
==> (2 a)
```

Comment: Fwiw there's a starred version of defun which accepts keyword arguments.

Answer (score 7):

Using dash:

```
(defun find-duplicates (list)
  "Return a list that contains each element from LIST that occurs more than once."
  (--> list
       (-group-by #'identity it)
       (-filter (lambda (ele) (> (length ele) 2)) it)
       (mapcar #'car it)))
```

A quick test suite:

```
(ert-deftest nothing ()
  (should-not (find-duplicates '())))

(ert-deftest no-duplicates ()
  (should-not (find-duplicates '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 "eight"))))

(ert-deftest single-duplicate ()
  (should (equal (find-duplicates '(1 2 3 4 1))
                 '(1))))

(ert-deftest multiple-duplicates ()
  (should (equal (sort (find-duplicates '(1 2 3 4 1 6 7 8 9 2))
                       #'<)
                 '(1 2))))

(ert-deftest string-duplicates ()
  (should (equal (find-duplicates '(1 2 "three" 4 "three"))
                 '("three"))))
```

It currently seems to return the items in the order of the first occurrence of each duplicate, but I don't see anything in `-group-by` that guarantees that, so I don't think that can be relied on. It could possibly be more efficient, using hashtables, but this works.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a non-hash version:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(defun find-duplicates (list)
  (loop for (item . count) in (let ((counts '())
                    place)
                (dolist (el list)
                  (setq place (assoc el counts))
                  (if place
                      (incf (cdr place))
                    (push (cons el 1) counts)))
                counts)
    if (> count 1)
    collect item))
#+END_SRC
```

Answer (score 1):

Reversing `delete-dups` using... `delete-dups` (and `seq`):

```
(defun report-dups (list)
  (delete-dups (seq-filter
                (lambda (el) (member el (cdr (member el list))))
                list)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to @caseneuve's definition.

```lisp
(defun report-dups (xs)
  (delete-dups (cl-remove-if-not (lambda (x) (member x (cdr (member x xs)))) xs)))
```

But both suffer from testing each element in the list, even if it has already been tested.  And then they run `delete-dups`.

This definition is straightforward, and it doesn't suffer from those inefficiencies:

```lisp
(defun report-dups (xs)
  (let ((ys  ()))
    (while xs
      (unless (member (car xs) ys) ; Don't check it if already known to be a dup.
        (when (member (car xs) (cdr xs)) (push (car xs) ys)))
      (setq xs  (cdr xs)))
    ys))
```

It also seems to be about 6 times faster than the hash-table solution (`get-duplicates`, above).